# UnityでAndroidのユーザーメールアドレスを取得する方法はあるでしょうか？

Tags: android, unity3d

こちらを参考にするとJavaでは、アカウントマネージャーから取得できるようですが
Unityで同じことするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

http://y-anz-m.blogspot.jp/2010/09/android_23.html

Google公式のプラグインを試すと、
アカウントの名前や、ユニークIDは取れるのですが
メールアドレスは見えないようです。(あるいはやり方わかってない)

playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity · GitHub 
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

メールアドレスはkickstarter支援者への特別アイテム配布への判定に使う予定です。
支援者のアカウントがUnityから特定できればいいのですが。

↓↓
[Unity(C#)からAndroid(Java)のActivityを拡張したクラスにアクセスしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6622/)

こちらが解決したので、Unityからもjavaで書いたアカウントマネージャーにアクセスし、メールアドレス取得できました。判定の一つに使えそうです。

Answer (score 1):

こんなissueを見つけました。

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/222#issuecomment-63825092

ニュアンスがよく分からないのでどなたか英語が上手い方、翻訳して下さい。
とりあえず言えるのは現行のplay-games-plugin-for-unityにはAPIは用意されてないそうです。